# Slack + Jenkins Как запустить сборку со slack?

Tags: jenkins, slack

Slack + Jenkins Как запустить сборку со slack?
Есть канал, на который приходят оповещения о сборках по расписанию.
Как запускать ручную сборку по сообщению в канал slack?

Пример:
Сообщение для Jenkins из Slack: build myNewProject.
Сообщение от Jenkins в Slack: myProject Success 1min 22sec

Плагины может какие есть? Или источники где покапать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать, например, через Jenkins REST API. Ссылка на него находится в правом нижнем углу каждой страницы (в конце URL добавляете /api/). Откройте /api/ для какой-либо Job и увидите справку как запустить данную сборку.

Comment: Спасибо, проверю - отпишу.

Comment: Да, действительно, мне предлагается использовать url api. А как через slack можно url отправлять?